# Unable to locate an element using Selenium WebDriver 2.31 (JRE 7)

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a scenario which books a bus ticket in a website. I'm using Selenium WebDriver with Eclipse and when i try to locate the element, i.e. 'Passenger name', no compilation errors, but while executing it shows an error such as "`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='i_passengerAge']"}`".

HTML and Java code below, also i need an hasty solution for this.

My System Info:

- Windows 7
- Selenium WebDriver 2.31
- Eclipse FW

**HTML of the WebPage:**

```html
<input name="i_passengerName" id="i_passengerName" maxlength="30" class="inputclass pageRequired commonInputStyle" title="Please enter your name!" type="text">

<input name="i_passengerAge" id="i_passengerAge" maxlength="2" size="4" class="inputclass fillAge digits commonInputStyle" type="text">
```

**My Automation Script:**

```java
WebElement PD_Name = driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerName"));
PD_Name.sendKeys(new String[] {"Testing"});
PD_Name.submit();

WebElement PD_Age = driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerAge"));
PD_Age.sendKeys(new String[] {"45"});
PD_Age.submit();
```

Comment: error shows 'id: i_passengerGender' element not found, can you provide html for that, Why do you need sumbit/clcik after setting text for each element?

Comment: html of the webpage: input type="text" name="i_passengerName" id="i_passengerName" maxlength="30" class="inputclass pageRequired commonInputStyle" title="Please enter your name!" style="background-color: rgb(248, 219, 219);">        input type="text" name="i_passengerAge" id="i_passengerAge" maxlength="2" size="4" class="inputclass fillAge digits commonInputStyle">

Comment: As @StaleElementException implies, you haven't shown us any HTML that contains an `i_passengerGender` element or any code that tries to find it.

Comment: @Ross Patterson.. **i_passengerGender** is the very next element to **i_passengerName**. i've shown it for example.. the error occurs for all the elements like i_passengerGender, i_passengerName,i_passengerAge...etc

Comment: @RajeshS Are you sure that the psngr name and age fields are not inside an iframe?

Comment: @HemChe s I'm.. my inputs are fetched via div NOT frame..

Comment: @RajeshS Then try using isDisplayed() and see if it is returning true.

Comment: @HemChe..  I tried..i couldn't get outa this. here is my script, plz dont mind if it looks very basic alike.. longing fa yo suggestion.........                                                               WebElement check=driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerGender"));
  if(check.isDisplayed())
   {
   System.out.println("Element is caught");
  
   }
  else
   {
   System.out.println("Not found....");
   }

Comment: tried isDisplayed().. but still cant locate the element...

Comment: @RajeshS, please try to avoid using the words "plz, some1, outa" and etc - that sound a bit unprofessional. As for you Error - can you please show what exception you are getting?

Comment: What is the StackTrace? Could you edit your question with it? "Unable to locate element" does not sound like a Java Exception.

Comment: @aimbire check it out. the exception i'm getting: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='i_passengerAge']"}**

Comment: @AlexOkrushko the exception i'm getting: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='i_passengerAge']"}**

Comment: is it since i'm accessing SSL certified https page?? i'm not clear still..

Comment: When i directly access the **passengerDetails** page.. i'm able to locate the elements.. but when i'm accessing from the begining (search bus->select bus-> **passengerdetails**), unable to locate them.. any siggestions...

Comment: where do you see Gender Element on your site [here](https://jetbus.in/getPassengerDetail.php)

Comment: @StaleElementException The very first element(right to the text 'Name')..It's a drop down..

Comment: It just seems you are not waiting the submit() method finish properly.

Comment: as @aimbire said you are not using wait properly, add wait condition on 'Passenger Details' page like header text to appear or something. once the page is loaded, start performing operation like selecting 'Title','Name'...and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you've tried to get the element with `By.id`, `By.cssSelector` or `By.xpath`.

Watch out about the `submit()` method. Because it search automaticaly the form to send and sometimes it may fail. That's why i prefere the good old `click()`.

By.id :

```
WebElement PD_Name=driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerName"));
PD_Name.sendKeys("Testing");
PD_Name.click();
```

By.xpath :

```
WebElement PD_Name=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='i_passengerName']"));
PD_Name.sendKeys("Testing");
PD_Name.click();
```

For the cssSelector way, you can take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Tell me if it improved. =)

EDIT :

Actually, there is no **i_passengerGender**

Comment: glad to receive a response. i tried your idea. But still the issue stands...longing for a solution. some1 help me outa this plz..

Comment: your input are into a form ? div ? ... ajax ?

Comment: my inputs are fetched via div

Comment: i've edited my OP, you probably must wait your ajax to load correctly and find you element.

Comment: Pardon, **i_passengerGender** is there.. I've just shown u the 2 fields(name & age) for ex... there are 7 fields, none of them be identified by my coding.

Comment: I suggest to use a wait for your element. Like [here](http://pastebin.com/XKRcdiAu)

Comment: My coding includes a few lines of **AutoIT scripts** which i call using Runtime() function.. i dont think that's the reason. will it be???

Comment: I don't know, i can't help you more... sorry

Comment: thanks :(.. one more thing..  
When i directly access the **passengerDetails** page.. i'm able to locate the elements.. but when i'm accessing from the begining (search bus->select bus-> **passengerdetails**),.. unable to locate them.. anyhow thanks mate...

Comment: passengerDetails is a form or a page ?

Comment: I've risen up this as a separate question. please read and try to answer..[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922741/webdriver-is-unable-to-locate-elements-but-it-locates-when-i-directly-access-th?noredirect=1#comment22680888_15922741)

Answer (score 2):

I myself am using C# so you will have to check the syntax here, but I believe your issue might be that you are accessing the elements too quickly (prior to the page **fully loading**). I would suggest trying the `WebDriverWait` class. I believe in Java it is something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, timeout);
wait.until(_driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerAge")));
```

After this line you can then safely access the element as you have confirmed it has fully loaded on the page.

Comment: thanks @Nashibukasan.. I tried this.. but "timeout cannot be resolved" error..i 've also included java.util package.. your suggestion to solve this please..

Comment: By `timeout` I meant you should create an `int timeout = 5;` where the value is how many seconds you want the timeout to be (in my example it's 5 seconds).

Comment: sleep starts and ends fine.. but my issue still unsolved.. here is my exception: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"i.passengerAge"}**

Comment: Are you positive that you have entered in the correct details for the element? This exception will only produce when the element is not found on the page. Try again with `wait.until(_driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerAge")));`.

Comment: this is my coding.check it please.  
**WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout);    
wait.until((Predicate) driver.findElement(By.name("i.passengerAge")));  
WebElement PD_Gender=driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerGender"));  
PD_Gender.click():
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='i_passengerGender']/option[2]")).click();  
WebElement PD_Name=driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerName"));  
PD_Name.sendKeys(new String[] {"Testing"});
PD_Name.click();  
WebElement PD_Age=driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerAge"));
PD_Age.sendKeys(new String[] {"45"});
PD_Age.click()**

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.name("i.passengerAge")));` is using the wrong **name**. It should be i_passenderAge according to the HTML you posted.

Comment: tried By.id()..but same exception..**Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"i_passengerAge"}**

Comment: I think you need to revisit your HTML and code. You appear to be searching incorrectly as this exception on throws if the element does not exist on the page at that time.

Comment: @ Nashibukasan checked my coding with HTML, no issues. and also consulted developers who built that webpage. Everything is correct.. it runs for one page(searching page), but NOT for this page(passenger details)..

Comment: @RajeshS, If it runs for one page, but not for the other there are 3 possible reasons: 1) the element has different `id`/`name` properties for different pages 2) You are not waiting long enough for element to appear 3) element on the other page in in `iframe`. There are NO other options. Try to eliminate them one-by-one.

Comment: @AlexOkrushko As u said above, (1) No, (2) No, (3) Yes. the other elements in same are in iframe. but the element what i try to locate is not in iframe.. any suggestion.!!?

Comment: @RajeshS, no other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in between these two lines means
    PD_Name.submit();
    WebElement PD_Age = driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerAge"));

After submitting you have to wait till entire page gets load.
According to this you have to modify the script and write waitForElementPresent(element) function.

In this case you script will be:`enter code here`

```
PD_Name.submit();
waitForElementPresent(i_passengerAge);
WebElement PD_Age = driver.findElement(By.name("i_passengerAge"));
```

Try this and let me know if its works or not.

Thanks,
Krishna.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check is this lies in a frame as HemChe said earlier, if it so you need to switch to that particular frame.

Answer (score 1):

1) First use wait command before enter text

2) Do not use "id" locator because its same for both

3) Use "class" locator instead, for both input element.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend after triggering any kind of web method example: click, keyboardType, etc..  use a `time.sleep(1)` this will give enough time to the browser to load the concatenated, new or loaded DOM added to the tree. If you dont give enough time it will be undefined.

Note: this code is used in python, use the equivalent code for java.