# WebDriver is unable to locate elements. But it locates when i directly access the webpage

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**Automation**: *Booking bus ticket*
**Description:**

1. WebDriver is **unable** to locate the elements when i enter into the
   webpage (*passengerDetails*)
2. But when i access that page (*passengerDetails*) directly, it **locates**
   the elements.

   Note: Accessing **SearchBus->SelectBus->SelectSeat->PassengerDetails** - Unable to locate..
       Accessing **directly PassengerDetails** -Able to Locate..  I guess, this is since the URL changes from **http to https**. Anyhow suggest me a solution for this..

Comment: is your bus site is live can anyone access your site [ possible duplicate of you own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898118/unable-to-locate-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver-2-31-jre-7]

Comment: @StaleElementException Yes it is a live site.. as you said, this question got up from my previous one. my previous one didn't 've any clear evidence. but it does.

Comment: provide url for your site , someone can look at their free time

Comment: @StaleElementException URL:http://www.jetbus.in. Hope you don't mind to give it a try..

Answer (score 1):

So your site is definitely using iframe type. Basically to make your code work, you need to switch back from "iframe" to your site.
try this code

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: +1, from a quick look, this page has *multiple* IFrames. Ouch! Seems likely this is his problem.

Comment: @buddy I'm 100% sure that the page **passengerDetail** doesn't  have the iframe.. the index page alone has the iframe type..

Comment: sure the passengerDetail doesnt have iframe, but somehow you need to get your focus back to the page after playing the iframe, with passenger seat selection

Comment: @buddy As you suggested, i used defaultContent(). but it's not switching to the default content. it just waits until i close the webdriver manually. one more thing. i don't even locate any element after switchTo().defaultContent(). i just try to print a message (using system.out.println("")).. even this print task is not executed..

Comment: please check the code posted by HemChe, It works fine. When not add some waiting method for page load, since page loading time takes quite a lot of time too

Comment: now i got an error message. it shows `Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.`

Answer (score 0):

Find Below the code for your requirement. It worked for me till the point of entering passenger details. Let me know if this was not you were looking for.

```
package org.com.selen;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class JetBus {

    protected static WebDriver driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Books&Tutorials\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("www.jetbus.in");
        driver.findElement(By.id("o_source")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("o_source")).sendKeys("Bangalore");
        driver.findElement(By.id("o_dest")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("o_dest")).sendKeys("Hyderabad");
        driver.findElement(By.id("departDate")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("11")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("search")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://jetbus.in/images/viewseats.png')]")).click();
```

//We need to switch to the fancybox frame before performing next set of operations

```
driver.switchTo().frame("fancybox-frame");
        driver.findElement(By.id("availableSeatImgId33")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("boardingPoint"))).selectByVisibleText("Hebbal - 11:05 pm");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"122989^11:05 pm\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("continue")).click();
```

//After you click Continue, it directly returns to passenger details page.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerGender"))).selectByVisibleText("Mr");
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerName")).sendKeys("JetBusPassenger");
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerAge")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerAge")).sendKeys("49");
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerMobile")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerMobile")).sendKeys("3698521463");
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerEmail")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("i_passengerEmail")).sendKeys("a_b@jetbus.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("ContinuePayNew")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.notAvailableDiv > a > span")).click();


    }

}
```

Comment: Huge thanks @HemChe. I used firefox driver instead of IE driver, it could not locate **http://jetbus.in/images/viewseats.png**  . anyhow i'm going to get IE Driver and  try with that.. i'll come back to you in minutes..thanks again.

Comment: Welcome Rajesh ! Type of driver, IE or FF driver is not an issue. You need to identify locators using Firebug or Selenium IDE.

Comment: @HamChe I tried your coding, and it's working fine till seat selection. after entering the passengerDetails, the WebDriver waits for a long time( doesn't show any error).. i used WebDriverWait, i dont think that's the reason...any suggestion.?